# how to add submenu item under parent menu item with code

Tags: actions

Well, here is my problem 
suppose i have a menu like this generated by wp_nav_menu()

```
home
test- test1, test2
contact
about
```

test is my custom post type

so what i want to do is if a user/admin publish posts a test post type i want it to automatically add in under test as test3.Forget about the publish_test hook i have done some research and i am ready to go with the code as follows in my functions.php

```
function auto_add_service_as_menu() {
    echo 'ok';exit;

}
function auto_remove_service_from_menu() {
    echo 'ok';exit;
}
add_action( 'publish_test', 'auto_add_service_as_menu' );
add_action( 'trash_test', 'auto_remove_service_from_menu' );
```

now what i want to do is add test3 which will be new test(cpt) post and its title and link should be automatically added to test menu.
Note: I don't want anything to add or remove in admin dashboard or admin menu only to the user(wp_nav_menu).
So any help would be helpful.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a custom [walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) for the navigation. You can check the post_type of every item and if it's your custom post type get the parent items.